# Difference between Parallel.ForEach(task.Wait) and Task.WaitAll

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

What is the difference between:

```
Parallel.ForEach(sometasks, x => x.Wait());
```

and

```
Task.WaitAll(sometasks);
```

**EDIT:**

Well I am not fully sure why I included Parallel into the question :/ ... What I had in mind was:

```
foreach(Task task in someTasks)
{
    task.Wait();
}
```

but I just included Parallel.ForEach thinking it is the same thing, while of course its not --- it spawns a thread for each task to wait, which is big overhead.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach(sometasks, x => x.Wait());` Doesn't makes sense for me

Comment: It makes sense to me as a learning exercise to me, +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though `Parallel.ForEach(sometasks, x => x.Wait());` makes no sense for me.

Short answer is

***Parallel.ForEach:*** With your code, blocks at least two threads. Calling thread and `ThreadPool` thread(s) as well.

**Task.WaitAll:** Blocks only the calling thread.

Answer (score 2):

The big difference between `WaitAll()` and calling `Wait()` in a loop is when one or more `Task`s fail:

- `WaitAll()` will always wait for all the `Task`s to complete, even if some of them fail. If more than one `Task` fails, it will throw an `AggregateException` that contains exceptions from all the failed `Task`s.
- `Wait()` in a loop will throw as soon as it encounters the first exception. That means it may not wait for all the `Task`s to complete and you're also going to learn only about one exception, even if there is more than one.

Answer (score 0):

`Parallel` class is designed to provide simple and efficient data-paralellism ( you distribute the SAME task on different data and then collect the result). Typical examples of these problems are vector or matrix processing problems (matrix multiplication, image processing etc).

`Task`s are designed for task-based parallelism - to help you structure a complicated asynchronious execution with possibility to handle task dependencies, failures etc.