# Difference between "foreach with task.Wait" and Task.WaitAll

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, wait

What is the difference between:

```
foreach(Task task in someTasks)
{
    task.Wait();
}
```

and

```
Task.WaitAll(sometasks);
```

In essence, looking from the end result perspective, they should be doing the same thing?

Comment: Yesterday I asked a similar question but which wasn't actually what I was looking for, because I asked it completely in a wrong way... 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174915/task-parallel-library-difference-between-parallel-foreach-task-wait-and-tas?rq=1

Comment: I think there could be a difference when one of the tasks get cancelled or throws an exception.

Comment: hmmm perhaps that is a good point, maybe WaitAll with throw an AggregateException containing exceptions from all the Wait() calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is in the exception handling. If `task.Wait();` throws, the `foreach` loop is exited. `WaitAll` will catch all exceptions and throw an `AggregateException` containing them.

See also: [Task.WaitAll and Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217643/task-waitall-and-exceptions)